# IPFS online node without IP address

Tags: ipv6, p2p, ipfs

During IPFS node explorer development we found some unusual online nodes without a valid IP in `Addresses` field. For example: `QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV`

Get the node info by [ipfs id](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/#ipfs-id) command.

**Query:**

`root@tux:~# ipfs id QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV`

**Response:**

```
{
"ID": "QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV",
"PublicKey": "CAASpgIwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDFhgftYoqapg+Y7wlWq67HA4O2c37jelJxUJqai0DyZMEeyQBzw4+Jc0VxPuXJNovb3SRIz9XCq3tyibbBs2JcZkHF+i9t8WERJth7c3rnLsEddPHAagW9nnBd+XxT4l9guZZtYOQ/YFZBTicZEdyKdc4fithz4QaweZqj/sa5lWYuaTTEA9y4Zikhh2NkM6gs0Suhamtym2boBrFaIJMfS7I1GLJecg1ap/fGTBsdmncQ4cEKnxpUAtGzLcsqukr9qkTYKeXP5imGvrm077A1mXwbPTKP1st5zmtZduRayIfOWvWtwhrfm1CrTpUzhu+XZsAn5sTO/Dk2QWnTiuNzAgMBAAE=",
"Addresses": [
    "/ip6/::1/tcp/4001"
],
"AgentVersion": "go-ipfs/0.4.17/",
"ProtocolVersion": "ipfs/0.1.0"
}
```

Got only IPv6 loopback address and no public one.

Now ping the node using [ipfs ping](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/api/cli/#ipfs-ping):

**Query:**

```
root@tux:~# ipfs ping -n 4 QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV
```

**Response:**

```
PING QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV.
Pong received: time=8.28 ms
Pong received: time=5.98 ms
Pong received: time=6.27 ms
Pong received: time=6.20 ms
Average latency: 6.68ms
```

How can it be up without an IP address? How to get the IP addresses of such nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than doing `ipfs id <PeerID>` you can ask the DHT of how it sees the peer by doing `ipfs dht findpeer <PeerID>`. In the case of `QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV` I see the following:

```
$ ipfs dht findpeer QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV

/ip4/192.168.10.11/tcp/4001
/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/4001
/ip6/::1/tcp/4001
/ip4/83.162.192.96/tcp/31885
/ip4/83.162.192.96/tcp/16803
```

If there is a case you want to see how **you** are connected to the peer, you can use `ipfs swarm peers` (peer you are currently connected to) together with `grep` (filtering output)

```
$ ipfs swarm peers | grep QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV

/ipfs/QmZSe5GZJb5jcKQZzQmdWaFtimTHafjvtxyMMTJy5nZ6hN/p2p-circuit/ipfs/QmRBRUCPY8saqzsLRyHexza3qUL8Wn9Zt59TcLMNnXF6zV
```

Comment: Thank you! Just tested and it works with the most IDs, but sometimes doesn't.

Comment: @YedigeDavletgaliyev yeah, that could happen if the DHT doesn't have any information on a particular peer (in the case of `ipfs dht findpeer`) or if you are not connected to the peer (in the case of `ipfs swarm peers`)